# How to test Olingo OData controllers?

Tags: java, testing, junit, odata, olingo

I'm trying to test my controllers with mock data on Olingo OData.

How should I set up the test and access the endpoints?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "view_name")
@Data
@Accessors(chain = true)
public class EntityName{
    @Id
    private int id;
}
```

```
@Repository
public interface RepositoryName extends JpaRepository<EntityName, Long> {}
```

I have repositories and entities which I would like to test but those classes have no methods.

(I need a simple test to validate the response type and content)